# How to find an element which its two childs match with two different values?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I want to use Python selenium to find the specific server on Speedtest website. For example, I want to find the server which its *host-location* is **Dagupan City** and *host-sponsor* is **USATV One Inc**.
Below is how the html code looks like. There will be lots of the same classname inside. What should I do to match with two different values from this?
Thanks!

```
<ul data-view-name="serverCollection" data-view-cid="view34" class=""><li data-model-cid="c184">
  <a data-server-id="11886" data-https-host="1">
      <span class="host-location">
        Dagupan City
      </span>
      <span class="host-sponsor">
        USATV One Inc
      </span>


  </a>
</li><li data-model-cid="c185">
  <a data-server-id="25314" data-https-host="1">
      <span class="host-location">
        Park City, Utah
      </span>
      <span class="host-sponsor">
        Utah Broadband
      </span>


  </a>
</li><li data-model-cid="c186">
  <a data-server-id="14515" data-https-host="1">
      <span class="host-location">
        Nagaoka
      </span>
      <span class="host-sponsor">
        CanopusAzusa
      </span>


  </a>
</li><li data-model-cid="c187">
  <a data-server-id="14890" data-https-host="1">
      <span class="host-location">
        Jakarta
      </span>
      <span class="host-sponsor">
        PT. Aplikanusa Lintasarta
      </span>


  </a>
</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
//a[span[@class='host-location' and contains(text(),'Dagupan City')] and span[@class='host-sponsor' and contains(text(),'USATV One Inc')]]
```

Demo:

[image]

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)
- [XPath Element that contains 2 children that each match a specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919218/xpath-element-that-contains-2-children-that-each-match-a-specific-text)

Comment: I use "find_elements_by_xpath" to implement you code and it works! However, it will get a list includes two elements. Is that normal? I can't find another element on my website.

Comment: Wouldn't `a[contains(., 'Dagupan City') and contains(., 'USATV One Inc')]` work just as well?

Answer (score 0):

you can also try like

```
//span[@class='host-sponsor'][contains(text(),'USATV One Inc')]/parent::a/span[contains(text(),'Dagupan City')]/parent::a
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the server with respect to its children `class` *attribute* `host-location` e.g. **Dagupan City** and `host-sponsor` e.g. **USATV One Inc** as the elements are dynamic elements, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired elements and you can use the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *XPath*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[span[@class='host-location' and contains(.,'Dagupan City')]]") and driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[span[@class='host-sponsor' and contains(.,'USATV One Inc')]]"))
  ```